# Gyroscope sensor: what is the axis around which the device's rotating?

Tags: sensors

i am coding 1 app which is same app "iHandy Level Free" on google play.
i am using gyroscope sensor, but i don't know what is the axis around which the device's rotating ? because when i rotate, tilt device, 3 values x, y, z are change too.
thanks

Comment: The Android follows ENU(east, North, UP ), have a look at this Application Mote : http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/jp/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00063297.pdf  convention , so you will get a bigger value for the axis around which the device is being rotated.

Answer (score 0):

The Android follows ENU(east, North, UP ), have a look at this Application Note : http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/jp/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00063297.pdf

convention , so you will get a bigger value for the axis around which the device is being rotated.
It is not possible to get a Zero value around any axis no matter how gently you move the device .You are bound get some angular rate around the tationary axis (which you are assuming to be stationary)